# modalPresentationStyle formSheet issues on iphone XR, XS Max

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I am displaying modal UIViewController with modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet but it has some issues on iphone XR and XS Max. It's displayed behind notch. Image bellow from left side iphone XR, XS, X.

[image]

UIViewController use autolayout and is presented like this:

```
let contentViewController = UINib(nibName: "EditViewController", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! EditViewController

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contentViewController)

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
let popover = navController.presentationController!
popover.delegate = self

self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

delegate:

```
extension MyController: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

There is same issue with modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet. It works fine with other modalPresentationStyles ie fullscreen

It's on iOS 12.1, swift 3

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I think you should report this one to apple.

Answer (score 1):

UIKit does not support that.

The only possibilities are `sheet to full screen` and `page sheet to form sheet` on iPad. As specified in the documentation :

> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

So UIKit already adapts it.

Unfortunately you will have to implement your own custom transition controller.

Comment: what do you mean by UIKit does not support that? I just want to fix this issue with sheet behind notch which is only on XR

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you're trying to use `formSheet` in a compact environment. UIKit does not support it. This is worst on smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

As [GaétanZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370312/2211019) said, better use another modal presentation style like overFullScreen for compact horizontal size clases and leave the formSheet for the horizontally regular ones.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    if controller.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
        return .formSheet
    }
    return .overFullScreen
 }
```